# Oracle database installation probs

Tags: oracle11g

[image]i can not install oracle 11g completely, it was  indicating ORA-01031: insufficient privileges,  with options - abort or ignore it. i pushed ignore but the installation has been frozen on a particular point after i cancel the popup box it still froze at that point. 
installing it on windows 10 64-bits .

Comment: We have no idea what platform you are on, which version you're installing or how, if you're following a tutorial or Oracle's docs, which steps you did (or didn't do), what it was doing when you got that error, which point it's now apparently stuck on - and most importantly what is being reported in the installation logs.

Comment: As pointed by @AlexPoole, provide details from the installation log files.

Comment: clone database creation that where it got stucked